# Error: The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: asp.net, .net, webforms, .net-3.5, viewstate

We have a legacy ASP.NET 3.5 Web Forms website.

We want to introduce multi-language feature to this old site, and as a short-cut, we are replacing strings in the rendering HTML string inside the `Render` method of the application lice-cycle. We are overriding it.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();

    base.Render(new HtmlTextWriter(output));

    string outputAsString = output.ToString();

    Translator.DoProcess(ref outputAsString);

    writer.Write(outputAsString);
}
```

Translator replaces the English words with Chinese words using a predefined CSV dictionary.

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> CHINESE = new Dictionary<string, string>();

public static void DoProcess(ref string htmlAsString)
{
    if (isValid && CURRENT_LANGUAGE == CHINESE_LANGUAGE)
    {
        htmlAsString = CHINESE.Aggregate(htmlAsString, (current, value) => current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value));
    }
}
```

It is all working fine, cool, wonderful, BUT until we use an UpdatePanel!

We have some functionality in the UpdatePanel which updates the page asynchronously, such as when a drop-down changes, another drop-down updates its values, and etc...

When we trigger events in the UpdatePanel, we are getting the following error on the client side on browser console after we got the response.

> Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message
> received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this
> error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(),
> response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled. Details:
> Error parsing near 'MENT||0|hiddenField|__LASTFOCUS||3972|hi'.

So, I assume the client-side cannot parse my translated HTML when using UpdatePanel/AJAX. I have checked the content of this AJAX request and the responses, and the response has my beautiful translations on place.

What I tried?

1. I tried to disable the ViewState on application level, as well as page level.
2. I tried to remove the ViewState hidden field completely from the site. It generated a different error.
3. I assumed that response content length might have been changed after translation, so I tried to change the content length as well when I translate the page.

None worked.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: The Render method at what time is it invoked? via a event button? you could include the code (aspx) of your page to see the location of the UpdatePanel

Comment: Are translations required at this point, during the dropdown's async postbacks? If you can handle the error (with no actions) would that be enough?